# xpath - how to show html only if vaklue exsist

Tags: xml, xpath, feed

noob question re xpath:

how to show HTML only if value in feed exist?

For the example if value:
{saleprice[1]}
exist in I want to show before it 
"Sale, only $" and "" after this value.
If value does not exist, nothing should be shown.

I would like to display above in HTML document.
Thanks

Comment: Can we see a sample of the XML? It'll be very useful to give you an answer

Comment: Thanks Bill, to clarify, I can not change xml, i can only edit my html or xpath files. xml is very simple, just bunch of values like:
<currency>​USD​</currency>
<saleprice>​898.​5​</saleprice>
<price>​898.​5​</price>
<retailprice>​2,​995.​00​</retailprice>
Is this helping or should i find more of the xml?